# setState using File onLoad

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having trouble setting the state with [FileReader's onLoad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload). The goal is to display multiple images and update the state.

I have read nearly all of the stackoverflow posts and I have tried my best to familiarize myself with the File/FileReader API. Yet, when I try to update my state- the React Developer Tools doesn't have by state updating.

I expect to see two photos on my page and my `photoList` state to be updated, however, it's not showing up.

```
class App extends Component{
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      photoList: []
    };
  }

 onSelectFile = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const { photoList } = this.state;
    const { imageFile } = event.target;

    for( let i = 0; i < imageFile; i++){
      let reader = new FileReader();
      let file = imageFile[i]

      reader.onload = (e) => {
        const { result } = e.target
        this.setState({
          photoList: [...photoList, result]
        })
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    }
  }


  render() {

    const { photoList } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" multiple onChange={this.onSelectFile} /> 
        <img src={ photoList } alt=""/>
      </div>       
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR, working example [there](https://codesandbox.io/embed/old-hooks-m01rp)

That is the list of fixes and improvements, what I found when reviewing your code:
1. You need to get props in the constructor and pass to `super`, if you inherited from React.Component
2. imageFile not correct property in event.target, instead of this you should use `files` which will contain updated files, and loop through `files` array

Comment: Thanks for the reply 
1.) I was under the impression that I could name the property attached to `event.property` anything that I wanted and that is why I named it `imageFile`. 
2.) I was able to update the state, however, if I select multiple photos, only one shows up. Is this because setState should not be in a for-loop?

Comment: ahhhhh yea... you know a lot of the stackoverflow answers have `setState` within the loop. I've found myself thinking- FileReader is executed in an async way. I would have to create a `Promise` that when resolved, would have to pass it's values (outside of it's for loop scope) to `setState`. Am I on the right path?

Comment: exactly, you also can use closures instead of Promises, but anyway Promises is good point, also you can use the asymc await

Answer (score 1):

You're giving an array of images to **img** and you're expecting it to handle it. Img tag can only accept one image at once:

```
<div>
        <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png" multiple onChange={this.onSelectFile} /> 
        { photoList && photoList.map(photo => <img src={ photo } alt=""/>) }
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for replying. That makes sense, however, my main concern is that my state isn’t updating. I’ll update this post with a photo of state. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ok I'll wait for your update. But have you tried my solution?